# How then include call and return without cannot implicit convert

Tags: api, .net-core, repository-pattern

I created a repository for calling the value from the intermediate schema that is contain **SchoolId** and **CourseId**.

My schema structure is given below.

**School**

```
 public class Schools
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string BannerUrl { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SchoolCourses> SchoolCourses { get; set; }
}
```

**Course**

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SchoolCourses> SchoolCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Intermidiated table that is: **SchoolCourse**

```
public partial class SchoolCourses
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public Guid SchoolsID { get; set; }
    public Guid CoursesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CoursesId")]
    public Course Courses { get; set; } // one school can have multiple courses.
    [ForeignKey("SchoolsID")]
    public Schools Schools { get; set; } // one course can have Multiple School.
}
```

Now I am crating a repository methods on the basis of the above schema and want to display all the course available in the school on the basis of school id.

**Here is repository class**:

```
public class SchoolCoursesRepository : ISchoolCoursesRepository
{
    public readonly learning_gpsContext _GpsContext = null;
    public SchoolCoursesRepository(learning_gpsContext GpsContext)
    {
        _GpsContext = GpsContext;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<SchoolCourses>> GetSchoolCourseForSchoolAsync(Guid schoolId)
    {
        var schoolsCourse = await _GpsContext.School.Where(x => x.ID == schoolId)
                           .Include(e => e.SchoolCourses)
                           .ThenInclude(c => c.Courses)
                           .ToListAsync();

        List<SchoolCoursesVm> schoolCoursesVms = new List<SchoolCoursesVm>();
         foreach (var course in schoolsCourse.SelectMany(x => x.SchoolCourses.Select(y => y.Courses)))
         {
             schoolCoursesVms.Add(new SchoolCoursesVm
             {

                  CourseName = course.Name,

             });
         }
         return schoolCoursesVms;
        }
```

**SchoolCoursesVm**:

```
public class SchoolCoursesVm
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is:

1. Unable to find explicit type for return the value.
2. Unable to call the **GetSchoolCourseForSchoolAsync** method in get api controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have return type as `ICollection<SchoolCourses>` , but try to return `List<SchoolCoursesVm>`

Change the return type to match the intended type

```
public async Task<ICollection<SchoolCoursesVm>> GetSchoolCourseForSchoolAsync(Guid schoolId) {
    var schoolsCourse = await _GpsContext.School.Where(x => x.ID == schoolId)
                       .Include(e => e.SchoolCourses)
                       .ThenInclude(c => c.Courses)
                       .ToListAsync();

    List<SchoolCoursesVm> schoolCoursesVms = new List<SchoolCoursesVm>();
    foreach (var course in schoolsCourse.SelectMany(x => x.SchoolCourses.Select(y => y.Courses))) {
        schoolCoursesVms.Add(new SchoolCoursesVm
        {
            Id = course.Id,
            CourseName = course.Name,
        });
    }
    return schoolCoursesVms;
}
```